# PCA, reverse coding, TIPI questionnaire used as predictor, ANOVA vs Multiple Regression

Tags: regression, pca, categorical-encoding

I am in the process of analyzing a questionnaire measuring attitudes: recording as predictors

1) gender, 
2) religion, AND 
3) the 10-item personality inventory (TIPI, 2003);

dependent variables should be the scores recorded in 4 different Likert-scale questionnaire (1=agree strongly, 4=disagree strongly). Some items are reverse-coded via the "transform"-"recode to different variables" option on SPSS, and so are the negatives in the TIPI questionnaire.

1) what type of factor analysis would be appropriate?
2) should I factor analyse the TIPI?
3) how do I continue?

(very generic, I know, but I could use some serious help!)

Comment: Could you spell out TIPI and maybe other acronyms too. I suspect many regulars wil not know TIPI.